I want to know various ways to check convergence of infinite product
In complex analysis class I learned some condition that makes infinite product converge.
Theorem : If $\sum |a_n|$ converges, then the infinite product $\prod(1+a_n)$ also converges.
The proof is simple, just using logarithm. My question is ; 'Is this the only way of testing convergence of infinite product?'
For example, if some product doesn't satisfy above condition, how can we know if it converges or not? I want to know many ways to test this.

It converges if and only if the sum of $\log(1+a_n)$ converges, so in principle all the tests for convergence of infinite sums are on the table.
